# How to bind an image used in a mask of a simulink block to said block?

Tags: image, simulink, mask, subsystem

To clarify this at the beginning:

With image inside the mask of subsystem i do **NOT** mean an image drawn onto the block, but rather an image one can add to the mask:[image: clarification]

Is there a way to bind the image to the block? In case I want to distribute my model, I don't want to have to share every image used in it.

For an image drawn onto the block I found a solution [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/simulink/2016/09/08/including-a-mask-image-in-your-block/), that is storing the image inside the UserData of the block, but I can't find an option to change the properties of images used inside a mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit too late, but having the same problem I 'fixed' it by including the image and its alpha values in the `'UserData'` parameter, checking if the image already exists in the current folder, and if not creating it from the userdata:

```
if ~exist('ARMicon.png','file')
    maskParams = Simulink.Mask.get(gcb);
    armim = maskParams.getDialogControl('armPic');
    ud = get_param(gcb,'UserData');
    imwrite(ud.ARM,'ARMicon.png','Alpha',ud.alpha);
    armim.FilePath = 'ARMicon.png';
end
```

[image: See the result]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems like a nice workaround until it gets featured in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

Quote out of my correspondence with the MathWorks Technical Support:

> Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to specify a mask dialog image without providing a file path and a separate image file. This has been brought to the attention of the development team as a possible enhancement for a future release.

This refers to Matlab / Simulink 9 (2016a).